# Error logging in to the WordPress dashboard

Tags: php, wordpress

I customized and changed WordPress login page by code snippet. After I successfully login to the site, I get the following error:

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\wamp64\www\xxx\wp-content\themes\xxx\header.php:60) in C:\wamp64\www\xxx\wp-includes\pluggable.php on line

How to fix this error?

How to fix this error?

Comment: Whatever you changed has presumably caused output to be generated somewhere before PHP then tries to issue a HTTP response header (perhaps for a redirect, or a session cookie, or response code, something like that). Since in a HTTP response the body cannot come before the header, that isn't allowed. The error message tells you where the unwanted output started, so begin your search there. Refer to the duplicate (in the blue box above) for more details on potential causes. And learn to google your error messages - it's vanishingly rare that you'll be the first person to experience it.